# Does ember.js support HasMany using just Em.Object.Extends?

Tags: ember.js

Currently my basic hello world ember app has the following model objects

```
ChatApp.User = Em.Object.extend({
    username: null,
    other: null
});

ChatApp.Message = Em.Object.extend({
    message: null
});
```

I'd like to improve this to be User HasMany Messages -can this be done as is? If not what is the preferred approach today in 0.9.8?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want to hold an array of ChatApp.message objects in ChatApp.User?

Comment: Would that make sense for a client side model (I assume it's valid)

Comment: Did you have a look to ember-data? It manages those kind of relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use ember-data.

It would give something like:

```
ChatApp.User = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  messages: DS.hasMany('ChatApp.Message')
});

ChatApp.Message = DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string')
  user: DS.belongsTo('ChatApp.User')
});
```

Comment: super newb question here -do I need another js file to use DS.Model? I noticed that DS.Model throws an exception in 0.9.8

Comment: You need to use ember-data.js. You can download it at http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.js  Possibly by ember.js 1.0 release it will be already included. There's an article about ember-data at http://emberjs.com/guides/ember-data-lifecycle/